# Magento cache product_id

Tags: magento, caching, containers, product

How do I retrieve my ProductId parameter from my container?

ANSWER: You dont retrieve a paramater from the container but from your block.
I've read the answers on stack, but none of them tells me how to retrieve the parameter from the container..

EDIT: Thanks to the answers I resloved my question! Working code below.

View.php: /app/code/local/Stackoverflow/Testcase/Block

```
class Stackoverflow_Testcase_Block_View extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

public function getParameters() {


    if (Mage::registry('current_product')) { 

        $product_id = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId(); 

    } else { 

        $product_id = $this->getProductId(); 

    }

    //Make sure we are not cached

    echo "time:".time()."<br/>";

    //This variable will be visible after the second load because it must be cached first!
    //NOTE that you are not able to save variables with an underscore ;-)

    echo "test_var:".$this->getTestVar()."<br/>";

    return "product_id: ".$product_id;

}

public function getCacheKeyInfo()
{
    $info = parent::getCacheKeyInfo();
    if (Mage::registry('current_product'))
    {
        $info['product_id'] = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
    }

    $info['test_var'] = "first second third";

    return $info;
}


}
```

Testcase.php: /app/code/local/Stackoverflow/Testcase/Model/Container

```
class Stackoverflow_Testcase_Model_Container_Testcase extends Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Container_Abstract { 



protected function _getIdentifier()
{
    return $this->_getCookieValue(Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Cookie::COOKIE_CUSTOMER, '');
}


protected function _getCacheId()
{
    return 'TESTCASE' . md5($this->_placeholder->getAttribute('cache_id') . ',' . $this->_placeholder->getAttribute('product_id')) . '_' . $this->_getIdentifier();
}


protected function _renderBlock()
{
    $blockClass = $this->_placeholder->getAttribute('block');
    $template = $this->_placeholder->getAttribute('template');

    $block = new $blockClass;
    $block->setTemplate($template)
        ->setProductId($this->_placeholder->getAttribute('product_id'))
        ->setTestVar($this->_placeholder->getAttribute('test_var'));



    return $block->toHtml();
}

protected function _saveCache($data, $id, $tags = array(), $lifetime = null) { return false; }  





}
```

testcase.phtml: app/design/frontend/xxx/default/template/stackoverflow

```
    $block_html = $this->getParameters();

    echo $block_html;

?>
```

Catalog.xml: app/design/frontend/ll/default/layout

`

```
    <label>Catalog Product View (Simple)</label>

    <reference name="product.info">

        <block type="catalog/product_view_type_simple" name="product.info.simple" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml">

            <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.simple.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">

                <label>Product Extra Info</label>

            </block>

            <block type="testcase/view" name="testcase" as="testcase" template="stackoverflow/testcase.phtml"/>

        </block>

    </reference>

</PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
```

`

default.phtml: app/design/frontend/xxx/default/template/catalog/product/view/

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('testcase') ?>
```

The code below is probably unrelevant but....
config.xml: /app/code/local/Stackoverflow/Testcase/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Stackoverflow_Testcase>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Stackoverflow_Testcase>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <testcase>
                <class>Stackoverflow_Testcase_Block</class>
            </testcase>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

cache.xml: /app/code/local/Stackoverflow/Testcase/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <placeholders>
        <stackoverflow_testcase>
            <block>testcase/view</block>
            <name>testcase</name>
            <placeholder>STACKOVERFLOW_TESTCASE</placeholder>
            <container>Stackoverflow_Testcase_Model_Container_Testcase</container>
            <cache_lifetime>1</cache_lifetime>
        </stackoverflow_testcase>
    </placeholders>
</config>
```

Stackoverflow_Testcase.xml: /app/etc/modules

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Stackoverflow_Testcase>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Stackoverflow_Testcase>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Thanks,

Martijn

Comment: Try doing a var_dump($this->getRequest()->getParam()) to get a list of all the variables, are you sure this is 'ProductId' and not 'productid'?

Comment: What is your url ... www.xyz.com/controller/method/productid/123?

Comment: catalog_product_view - then my `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('testcase') ?>` is called in the `product_type_data` block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Container_Sidebar_Cart` Container for an example :

> file:
>   app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/Model/Container/Sidebar/Cart.php

```
$renders = $this->_placeholder->getAttribute('item_renders');
```

In order to access a variable in your container, you need to add it to your `cachekeyinfo` in the Block class :

> file : app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Sidebar.php

```
public function getCacheKeyInfo()
    {
        $cacheKeyInfo = parent::getCacheKeyInfo();
        $cacheKeyInfo['item_renders'] = $this->_serializeRenders();
        return $cacheKeyInfo;
    }
```

**edit:**

try this in your container :

```
protected function _renderBlock()
    {
        $blockClass = $this->_placeholder->getAttribute('block');
        $template = $this->_placeholder->getAttribute('template');

        $block = new $blockClass;
        $block->setTemplate($template)
            ->setProductId($this->_placeholder->getAttribute('product_id'););
        return $block->toHtml();
    }
```

and try this in your block :

```
public function getCacheKeyInfo()
    {
        $cacheKeyInfo = parent::getCacheKeyInfo();
        $cacheKeyInfo['product_id'] = $this->getRequest()->getParam('ProductId');
        return $cacheKeyInfo;
    }
```

Comment: With getCacheKeyInfo() it returns this: `code array(4) { [0]=> string(9) "BLOCK_TPL" [1]=> string(2) "nl" [2]=> string(57) "frontend/<>/default/template/stackoverflow/testcase.phtml" ["template"]=> string(28) "stackoverflow/testcase.phtml" } code` but no product_id.. for some reason we cant save it in the cache.

Comment: The whole point is that you need to add it yourself ... like in the exxample I linked. You have to modify your block's getCacheKeyInfo function

Comment: yes that makes sense (ofcourse). It is set in the _renderBlock() method. but how do I set an productID ? I tried: `code      $block = new $blockClass;
     $block->setTemplate($template)
      ->setProductId(232);
     
     return $block->toHtml(); code` Unfortunatly it wont be received in the getCacheKeyInfo [I've updated my code]

Comment: you must do the contrary, save the product ID in the BLOCK's getCacheKeyInfo method and retrieve it in your Container.

Comment: I get what you mean but I dont have a clue how to do this.. Are you able to edit my post? Thanks

Comment: I do appreciete your effort but still no success :( When I try to set the productId in getCacheKeyInfo it stays empty.. What I did find in the core module is that they set a mage:register in there `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php` . But I am not able to retrieve the mage:register in my getParams() function.

Comment: basic logic for block/container variable passing through is well detailed here: nothing more to say about that. you must have another issue with a part of your specific code while retrieving somehow your productId..